# AngularCLI+ng-packagr: Using 3rd party library with css dependencies like Leaflet for an angular component library

Tags: angular, sass, leaflet, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I'm creating an Angular component library providing several UI components. This library will be imported with npm in another angular project. For a major part of my components, it worked fine except for one which needed 3rd party library css file with image url link (Leaflet).

My component library follows the article written by
[Nikolas LeBlanc about building a component library with Angular CLI and ng-packagr](https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e).

The project structure is the following:

```
├── src
│   ├── app
│       ├── app.component.html
│       ├── app.component.spec.ts
│       ├── app.component.ts
│       ├── app.component.scss
│       ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── component1
│       ├── component1.component.html
│       ├── component1.component.spec.ts
│       ├── component1.component.ts
│       ├── component1.component.scss
│       ├── component1.module.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── typings.d.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── styles.scss
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── .angular-cli.json
├── tslint.json
```

Ng-packagr performs well the bundling into a usable npm library for other project, the structure is like this:

```
├── ui-components
│   ├── ui-components.es5.js
│   ├── ui-components.js
├── bundles
│   ├── ui-components.umd.js
├── src
│   ├── app
│       ├── app.component.d.ts
│       ├── app.moduled.d.ts
├── package.json
├── public_api.d.ts
├── ui-component.d.ts
├── ui-component.metadata.json
```

In order to use the Leaflet library , I had to import css files in my component sass file

location-component.component.scss

```
@import '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
@import '~leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css'
@import '~leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css'
@import '~leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css'
```

location-component.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
import 'leaflet-draw';
import {
  ComponentLocationInterface
} from '../interfaces/component-location.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-location',
  templateUrl: './component-location.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-location.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ComponentLocationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: ComponentLocationInterface;
  controlDrawLayer: L.Control.Draw;
  leafletMap: L.Map;
  drawnItems: L.FeatureGroup;
  featureCollections: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any>[] = [];
  constructor() {
  }
  ...
```

leaflet.css and leaflet-draw.css are using a folder called images/ to import icons for the map. After the ng-packagr run, my bundled component contains leaflet style but with broken link to the images folder.

ui-components.umd.js (ng-packagr bundled file)

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
      background-image: url(images/layers.png);
      width: 36px;
      height: 36px; }
```

When this npm package is installed in a test project, I have the map without the icons because the browser requests them through http requests.

Test project app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentLocationModule } from 'ui-components';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ComponentLocationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Leaflet Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6uQo.png)

[Browser requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orlp4.png)

A possible workaround was by going out of the angular-cli and ng-packagr environment and using webpack with Postcss plugins to transform images url into base64 images, but I did not manage to make a working bundle because the bundling result was very different from my original project configuration.

In a nutshell, my only way to make my component working is to import the leaflet css file in the project which uses the component library.

Is there a way to integrate those images in my angular component library instead of making a dependency in the project using this library?